# client to server push notification?

Tags: android, notifications, server, client, push

I see lots of tutorials and articles online about **Push Notifications**, especially from Android devices. I'm wondering how you would send updates *from* your mobile device to a server. Or would the mobile device be the server in this scenario? Essentially, I aim to have a website set up where I can send notifications/updates/etc. to from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

From Mobile you can call **Webservice** and send data to database server.

Push Notification mechanism is for Mobile devices.

For server to mobile you can use **Push Notification**. From Mobile to server Use Webservice

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your own server, in general, you have to create a **Web Service**, one of the most common ways now is [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web service,

Alternatively, as you are asking about Android, you should take a look at this

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

which provide upstream message, i.e. send from Android devices to server